# Synchronize zoom between multiple charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In the below fiddle, how do I synchronize x-axis zoom of all three charts? Thank you.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mbfhqsLx/62/

```
function syncZoom(target, e) {
        var chart = $(target).highcharts(),
            min, max;
        min = e.min === null ? e.dataMin : e.min;
        max = e.min === null ? e.dataMax : e.max;
        syncing = true;
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max);
        syncing = false;          
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `afterSetExtremes()` to implement synchronized zoom:

```
  xAxis: {
    events: {
      afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
        Highcharts.charts.forEach(chart => {
          chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(event.min, event.max);
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w5890cen/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Just a quick question: I believe event.min, event.max would be the area zoomed(min and max) values?  If yes, is it dynamically set for all charts, whenever an area is zoomed?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly - yes, the min and max set a zoomed area range (extremes). Looping through all charts we are able to dynamically set extremes for each of them.